# Error while accessing Lex Bot from react native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-lex

I have a Lex Bot setup and working fine with Android. But when I try to access the same from react native, I get the following error:

```
NotFoundException: There is no alias named test for the bot named test_bot_name. Choose another alias.
```

I am using the aws-sdk-react-native package. My call to Lex looks like this:

```
sendToLex(message) {
    let params = {
        botAlias: 'test',
        botName: 'test_bot_name',
        inputText: message,
        userId: lexUserId,
    }
    lexRunTime.postText(params, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            // TODO SHOW ERROR ON MESSAGES
            console.log("[ERROR] Error: " + err);
            console.log("[ERROR] Data: " + data);
        }
        if (data) {
            console.log("Data " + data);
            this.showResponse(data)
        }
    })
}
```

The same botAlias and botName parameters work fine on Android. But does not work on react native. The AWS config credentials look fine as I am not getting errors relating to the identity pool and region.

Answer (score 0):

If it does indeed work in Android as you say then I would suggest the following:-

- Ensure that the credentials are for the correct account
- Ensure that you're pointing to the correct region

Try creating another alias and testing that to discount any funnies in the system.